# Different performance of counting features in ogr.Layer returned from ExecuteSQL

Tags: gdal, sql, ogr, sqlite, pyqt

I am working on a `PyQt5` desktop application [GDBee](https://github.com/AlexArcPy/GDBee) which allows executing SQL queries against Esri file geodatabases using `GDAL`. My development environment is Windows 10 64bit, Python 3.5, and Python bindings for `GDAL` 2.1 / 2.2. I use the built-in `OpenFileGDB` driver (read-only access).

This is the minimal code you need to reproduce the problem. The data are coming from the [PostGIS workshop materials by Boundless](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/index.html) (shapefiles have been loaded into a file geodatabase as is).

```
import time
import ogr
ds = ogr.Open(r"NYC.gdb")

res = ds.ExecuteSQL('select * from streets', dialect='SQLITE')

start_time = time.time()
print(('Number of feats using len', len(res)))
end_time = time.time()
print(('Time with len', end_time - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
print(('Number of feats using GetFeatureCount', res.GetFeatureCount()))
end_time = time.time()
print(('Time with GetFeatureCount', end_time - start_time))

res = ds.ExecuteSQL('''SELECT
    Polys.Name AS NeighborhoodName
    , Count(*) AS CrimeCount
FROM
  Homicides AS Points
JOIN
  Neighborhoods AS Polys
ON
    ST_Contains(Polys.Shape, Points.Shape) = 1
AND
    Points.YEAR in (2008, 2009, 2010)
GROUP BY
    Polys.Name
ORDER BY
    CrimeCount DESC
LIMIT 10
''', dialect='SQLITE')

start_time = time.time()
print(('Number of feats using len', len(res)))
end_time = time.time()
print(('Time with len', end_time - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
print(('Number of feats using GetFeatureCount', res.GetFeatureCount()))
end_time = time.time()
print(('Time with GetFeatureCount', end_time - start_time))
```

The output:

```
('Number of feats using len', 19091)
('Time with len', 0.022000551223754883)
('Number of feats using GetFeatureCount', 19091)
('Time with GetFeatureCount', 0.021004199981689453)
('Number of feats using len', 10)
('Time with len', 5.007046937942505)
('Number of feats using GetFeatureCount', 10)
('Time with GetFeatureCount', 5.008031845092773)
```

I have noticed that the performance of getting the number of features returned by a complex SQL query takes a lot longer (5 secs) even though the number of features is tiny (just 10 features). It *can* have something to do with the spatial functions, but I am not completely sure. The performance of the `len` and the `GetFeatureCount` is practically identical.

**Does anyone know why getting the length of features in the Layer object returned is different depending on the SQL query executed and if there is any way to make it faster?**

Answer (score 1):

First, you get the same count for `len` as for `GetFeatureCount` because the former is a [wrapper](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr-pysrc.html#Layer.__len__) to the latter.

The [doc](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#a74c796d4ce712e9a78df6042eeb8a91a) says that `GetFeatureCount` can have to scan the entire layer to count the feature, so it is basically running the expensive SQL again. You can investigate spatial indexes or move the data to [memory](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#load-data-to-memory) for faster access.

Comment: Good link to the memory, will look into. The spatial indexes are not supported when using the `OpenFileGDB` driver; I've updated the question to include this.